# Listbox items in edit mode in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

In add store page,i have a category listbox displaying list of categories from the table category in db.

The code for category listbox in add store is

```
<select id="category" multiple="multiple" name="category">
<?php
$ct_query="SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY category_id ASC";
$ct_sel=mysql_query($ct_query);
while($ct_res=mysql_fetch_array($ct_sel))
          {
if($row['category_id'] == $ct_res['category_id'])
                  echo "<option value='".$ct_res['category_id']."' selected=selected>".$ct_res['category_name']."</option>";
              else
                  echo "<option value='".$ct_res['category_id']."'>".$ct_res['category_name']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

In edit store page, the same listbox is there.When i select a single category in the listbox in add store page, it displays correctly in edit store page.But  when i select  multiple items in listbox in  add store page,the selected listbox items is not displayed in edit store page.The code for category list box in edit store page is

```
    <select id="category" multiple="multiple" name="category">
          <?php
          $ct_query="SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY category_id ASC";
          $ct_sel=mysql_query($ct_query);

          while($ct_res=mysql_fetch_array($ct_sel))
          {
if($row['category_id'] == $ct_res['category_id'])
                  echo "<option value='".$ct_res['category_id']."' selected=selected>".$ct_res['category_name']."</option>";
              else
                  echo "<option value='".$ct_res['category_id']."'>".$ct_res['category_name']."</option>";
 }

          ?>
</select>
```

In edit store page,the multi selected listbox items should be displayed correctly,when i select multiple items from listbox in add store page.

I have tried various codes.Nothing worked.Provide me a valuable solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the same code to list all items even if you want to show, edit, etc,
You need to use mysqli instead mysql, and the code must be something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name FROM category ORDER BY id ASC;";
$result = connection()->query($sql);
$rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "<select id='category' multiple='multiple' name='category'>";
while ($rs != ''){
   echo "<option id='".$rs['id']."' value='".$rs['id']."'>".$res['name']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Then if you have some stored on database you can read selected items and mark as selected with jQuery (if i dont remember wrong it must be something like:  `$('#idselected').attr(select selected);` )